# How to resolve the error in Keras Neural Networks implementation from the wine dataset

Tags: python, pandas, keras, scikit-learn

I am using the below mentioned code to run a neural network in Keras. There are 3 unique target variables and 13 input variables. I am getting the error : ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((5, 3) vs (5, 121)). I cannot figure out the error here. Can someone help

```
import pandas
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from keras.utils import np_utils
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
# load dataset

dataset = pd.read_csv("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine/wine.data")#,header=None)
dataset.columns = ['Class label','Alcohol','Malic acid','Ash','Alcalinity of ash','Magnesium','Total phenols','Flavanoids','Nonflavanoid phenols','Proanthocyanins','Color intensity','Hue','OD280/OD315 of diluted wines','Proline']
dataset = dataset.values
Y = dataset[:,13]
X = dataset[:,0:13]
encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(Y)
encoded_Y = encoder.transform(Y)
# convert integers to dummy variables (i.e. one hot encoded)
dummy_y = np_utils.to_categorical(encoded_Y)
 
# define baseline model
def baseline_model():
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(15, input_dim=13, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.add(Dense(3, activation='sigmoid'))
    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
 
estimator = KerasClassifier(build_fn=baseline_model, epochs=10, batch_size=5, verbose=0)
results = cross_val_score(estimator, X, dummy_y, cv=RepeatedKFold(n_splits=10, n_repeats=10))
print("Baseline: %.2f%% (%.2f%%)" % (results.mean()*100, results.std()*100))
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: error should show you in which line you have problem and you could use `print()` to see what you have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it should be first what you should do to check problem. If problem is `shape` then you should check shapes in variables.

Answer (score 1):

Your error says that your model output is 3 dim but your labels are of 121 dims.
I believe the reason is `Y = dataset[:,13]` which does not contain `class_labels` and might have unique 121 value because of that your `one_hot` has 121 dims vector.

Try:

`Y = dataset[:,0]` as it is `class_label` and have values `{1,2,3}` (3 classes).
PS: accordingly change `X` too (I have no idea about this dataset).